# Repairing broken power steering pump mounts

Tags: mercedes-benz, power-steering

[image: looking at PS pump still attached to broken brackets][image: looking at area where PS pump mounts]I replaced the power steering pump in my Mercedes and after Two days the mounts which are attached to what looks like the engine broke off.  Not the mounts on the pump.  What is the best way to fix the broken mounts?  Thank you so much in advance for your help, I'm in a tough spot right now and not sure what to do.

Comment: can you post pictures of the break? if it's aluminum you need to have someone that can tig weld do the repair or replace the whole bracket.

Comment: Have any pics to get a visual of what you are dealing with?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I'll post a couple of pictures in original thread

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure if welding would work or not, to be honest.  My biggest concern is obviously the strength of the weld and being able to hold since the PS pump is right on the corner of the belt and seems to carry most of the stress from the belt.  As far as a bracket, I dont know if there is a bracket or if its a part of the engine cast itself?  Both great questions, wish I knew the answers for.  Hopefully the pics will help.

Comment: @DucatiKiller  You're welcome, hope it helps!  Thanks for looking' out!

Comment: I couldn't find a exploded diagram doing a quick search, but I think the mounts are part of the timing cover. I'd try cleaning the area and having a good look at the assembly. The mounts are probably cast aluminum and the bracket/timing cover would need to be removed anyways for a welder to get a good clean weld on it. An alternative would be to look for another mounting point and make a mounting bracket out of 1/8" steel. Either way it doesn't look good and involves a lot of work.

Comment: @Ben  I think you're right, unfortunately for me.  ha..  The original power steering pump that came off the vehicle did have a couple more mounting spots which went directly in to the timing cover and weren't those 'ears' which broke.  There were Four total, instead of Two.  I think I'll try a mounting plate, I like your idea of using steel.  Thank you for the feedback and taking the time you did, I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 1):

Is that a timing chain cover that it bolts to?  If so, first choice would be to replace the broken parts.   2nd choice, if its aluminum, get it super clean and weld it.

The problem you having addressed is that fact that it broke in the first place.  It means it was over stressed and probably stressed in a way the factory never intended.   I would lean toward it not being installed correctly (or even simply not being tensioned correctly).  Use a torque wrench in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the issue! From the images you showed here I must say you have a tougher fix than any easy solution. You see from just the photos I would expect to have to replace the housing this attached to, and I don't think it's part of the block, but I have limited information as to the year, engine size model etc. to do my diligence for you with some research. A general observation is that something was either forced in place, forced off possibly by not seeing a bolt and prying or forced in place by tightening the bolts to "suck it in place". This weakens the metal due to excess force on the threaded mount area. As mentioned, I have no searchable info other than Mercedes engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the screws are loose, the 2 of the low and the rear one. You only see the two on the top and they look ok, then the mount cracks apart.

Try welding and using a screw lock like Loctite in the 5 screws.

Comment: I don't know what they do in Argentina, but welding oily cast aluminum is going to be quite the *magnífica solución artesanal*.  And I'm not sure how loctite will help with the OP's issue.  It looks to me like expensive original brackets are needed, perhaps from a junk/scrap/breaker's yard.  Best of Luck!

Comment: Yes, agreed. Invest in new or used brackets. Some vendors even sell after market less expensive brackets. If the weld comes off good luck with all the accessories, crank pulley and surrounding irmc.